# Connecting Sunpak 2-pin flash plug to JJC BP external battery pack

Tags: flash, power

Would you have any suggestions about hooking up the JJC BP (the one with interchangeable power cable for Nikon, Canon, Sony) to a Sunpak DR12X or 36DX flash with 2-pin plug? Would you know the polarity of the two pins on the Sunpak flashes? There is also a 2-pin to 3-pin adapter for the flash; if polarities match, could we use say the connecting cord for Canon? Too many questions!

Comment: Do you have one of the 2-pin to 3-pin adapters now? If not, they are still available on eBay and elsewhere.  I would expect the adapter to be set up for the correct polarity and would work just fine.

Comment: Yes indeed- except that I am not sure that the JJC battery pack uses the common DIN connectors used by Quantum and Godox and others for their HV (high-voltage) connectors. Since JJC don't make a connector for Sunpak (the CS4 cable for 2-pin or CS5 for 3-pin plug), I'm wondering whether the canon cable will fit (not that I will actually try it and possibly blow things up!)